# requestFocus() method not working for edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-method

I have an 2 edit texts, one of them is visible and other is not. I have set visibility "gone" for the invisible one. Now when I click input method next from edittext one, I make edittext two visible and request focus there, it gets visible but focus is not there. Interesting thing is I made visibility "invisible" instead of "gone". here is the code...

```
 option1.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT){                   
                option2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                option2.requestFocus();                   
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Think about this... You are `IME_ACTION_NEXT`-ing into one EditText, so the focus goes there. Why are you trying to force focus to a different EditText?

Comment: I think u didn't get my problem...After I finish typing in option one and press input next button it should make invisible edit text visible as well as take cursor there...

Comment: Sure. But I still don't understand. When you "tab" to the next input, focus should be placed there. Is that not happening?

Comment: no it is not going to next edittext...\

Comment: Alright, then can you provide a [mcve] so we can try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: sir this is the code I am using nothing else than that which has been mentioned here in the question... in xml option 2's visibility is "gone"...

Comment: I understand that, I'm trying to help you. Please [edit] to show the XML and the parts of the Activity where you load these views

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it will work or not.
But your setOnEditorActionListener() is returning false, make it to return true.